# The specified service does not exist (Win 7 x64)

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-services, windows-7-x64

We have an application that installs and accesses a service on the machine.
On one machine, that is Windows 7 x64, it produces the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   The specified service does not exist
>   as an installed service

The user is an admin user and I have installed it on other Windows 7 x64 machines without an issue.

The service is listed in the services.msc, and in the 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services and is running under 'Local System'.

I have installed and uninstalled many times, checking to make sure that the service was uninstalled/reinstalled properly but the application still produces that error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting hit with WOW64 Redirection - is your EXE a 32-bit EXE?